# C# Passing DataSet through Custom Button Class Doesn't work

Tags: c#, excel, button, dataset, click

I'm trying to invoke a method through a button, but the problem is that I need to pass a DateSet when cliking the button, because it will be used in the method. Therefore I have created a Custom Button Class that will pass the DataSet to the method. This method will create an excel document from the Tables within the DataSet.

When invoking this method directly in Page_Load it's working fine, but I want to have the Excel document created when clicking "Export to Excel". The problem is that the DataSet "set" doesn't seem to be passed thorugh the click event properly. I guess the problem is the Button Class.

Does anyoe know how to solve this? The DataSet seems to be lost on the way to the createExcel method.

I get the error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on the first for loop within the method (on dataset.Tables.Count).

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable table1 = new DataTable();
        table1.Columns.Add("Table1_Col1");
        table1.Columns.Add("Table1_Col2");
        table1.Rows.Add("Table1_Row1_Item1", "Table1_Row1_Item2");
        table1.Rows.Add("Table1_Row2_Item1", "Table1_Row1_Item2");

        DataTable table2 = new DataTable();
        table2.Columns.Add("Table2_Col1");
        table2.Columns.Add("Table2_Col2");
        table2.Rows.Add("Table2_Row1_Item1", "Table1_Row1_Item2");
        table2.Rows.Add("Table2_Row2_Item1", "Table1_Row1_Item2");

        DataSet set = new DataSet();
        set.Tables.Add(table1);
        set.Tables.Add(table2);

        Response.Write(set.GetXml());

        MyButton btnExcel = new MyButton();
        btnExcel.DsDataSet = set;
        btnExcel.ID = "excel";
        btnExcel.Text = "Export to Excel";
        btnExcel.Click += new EventHandler(this.Button1Click);
        form1.Controls.Add(btnExcel);
    }

    protected void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        DataSet ds = (sender as DataSet);
        createExcel(ds);
    }

    protected void createExcel(DataSet dataset)
    {
        //Print using Ofice InterOp
        Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
        var workbook = (Excel._Workbook)(excel.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value));

        // Object reference not set to an instance of an object
        for (var i = 0; i < dataset.Tables.Count; i++)
        {
            if (workbook.Sheets.Count <= i)
            {
                workbook.Sheets.Add(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            }

            //NOTE: Excel numbering goes from 1 to n
            var currentSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[i + 1];

            for (var y = 0; y < dataset.Tables[i].Rows.Count; y++)
            {
                for (var x = 0; x < dataset.Tables[i].Rows[y].ItemArray.Count(); x++)
                {
                    currentSheet.Cells[y + 1, x + 1] = dataset.Tables[i].Rows[y].ItemArray[x];
                }
            }
        }

        string outfile = @"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop\EXCEL_TEST.xlsx";

        workbook.SaveAs(outfile, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
                        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing);
        workbook.Close();
        excel.Quit();
    }
}

public class MyButton : Button
{
    private DataSet m_DsDataSet;

    public DataSet DsDataSet
    {
        get { return m_DsDataSet; }
        set { m_DsDataSet = value; }
    }

}
```

Comment: so on the Page_Load why are you trying to invoke a Button Click also have you actually stepped thru the code.. ? `protected void Button1Click` put a break point in this method is this a web app or winforms app..? everything looks good up until this `btnExcel.Click += new EventHandler(this.Button1Click);
        form1.Controls.Add(btnExcel);` not really sure why you are adding and or creating a new button but I can see data when testing everything you have up until you create this odd Class that inherits from `Button` please confirm that you debugged the code

Answer (score 0):

The exception results from the line:

```
DataSet ds = (sender as DataSet);
```

The parameter `sender` is a `Page` object, not a `DataSet`, which will result in `ds` being assigned a null value.

In your code, `set` is a local variable.  The simplest solution is to promote `set` to a field of the `Page` so that it is in scope when `Button1Click` is invoked.  This can be done like so:

```
DataSet set; // set is a field of the class, rather than a local variable
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable table1 = new DataTable();
    ** Lines removed **
    this.set = new DataSet(); // set should be an instance variable
    set.Tables.Add(table1);
    set.Tables.Add(table2);
    ** Lines removed **
}

protected void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    DataSet ds = this.set;
    createExcel(ds);
}
```

`Page_Load` is called prior to `Button1Click` when the page loads.  In the code above, `Page_Load` initializes `set` to the required dataset.  When `Button1Click` is invoked, it can simply reference `set` to obtain the initialized `DataSet` instance.  It is consequently not necessary to explicitly pass the dataset as a parameter to `Button1Click`.